# why this two select statement doesnt' give same answer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i'm using oracle 11g. i want to know why these two query giving different answer?

logically they are same:

```
   select * from tableA where 
   exists (select * from tableB where tableA.ID != tableB.ID);

   select * from tableA where 
   not exists (select * from tableB where tableA.ID = tableB.ID);
```

in the first one i'm selecting every thing that not exist.

in the second one i'm not selecting everything that exist.

note ("exist" changed to "not exist) and ("!=" changed to "=")

look same right? but they give totally different answer

Answer (score 3):

This statement is probably going to return all values in A:

```
select *
from tableA 
where exists (select * from tableB where tableA.ID != tableB.ID);
```

The only time a row will fail to match is when it is the same as *all* rows in `TableB` that have a non-NULL values in `ID`.  So, if `TableB` has at least two rows with different `id`s, then all rows in `tableA` will be returned.

This statement:

```
select *
from tableA 
where not exists (select * from tableB where tableA.ID = tableB.ID);
```

Is saying that there is no `id` in `TableB` that matched the id in `TableA`.  This would be what you want 99% of the time.

Comment: +1, but there are possibility to have more than 1 row for first case: 2nd row must contain `null` in `ID` field.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement returns A values different from any B value.
The second statement returns A values different from all B values.